# How to write database retry connection logic in TypeScript or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to write a JavaScript function to connect to MySQL database and in case the database is not available for any reason e.g. database is down for maintenance, network failure, etc., then the `connect` function should retry connecting every 5 seconds. The `connect` function should not return control to the caller and should not throw an exception.

I have written the following code but not sure if it will work. Could anyone provide the correct implementation of such a function?

Similarly `query` function should not return control on exception rather it should retry every 5 seconds and only return when records are selected using `sql`.

```js
const mysql = require("mysql");

class Database {
  databaseName: string | undefined;

  connection: any;

  config?: {
    host: string;
    user: string;
    password: string;
    port: string;
    database?: string;
  };

  constructor() { }

  public connect(config) {
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
    this.config = config;

    this.connection.connect((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(`Error connecting to the database, retry in ${process.env.DB_RETRY_INTERVAL}ms. Error=[${err.message}]. Host=[${this.config.host}]. Port=[${this.config.port}]`);
        
        setTimeout(async () => {
          await this.connect(config);
        }, parseInt(process.env.DB_RETRY_INTERVAL));
      } else
        console.log(
          `Database connection established for: ${this.config.database}`
        );
    });
  }


  public async query(sql: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.connection.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(`Error executing sql ${sql}, retry in ${process.env.DB_RETRY_INTERVAL}ms. Error=[${err.message}]. Host=[${this.config.host}]. Port=[${this.config.port}]`);

          setTimeout(async () => {
            await this.query(sql);
          }, parseInt(process.env.DB_RETRY_INTERVAL));
        } else {
          resolve(rows);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

export default Database;
```

Comment: _"not sure if it will work"_ - did you consider _testing it_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I tested it and it is retrying after every 5 seconds in case of connection failure. What I am not sure if `connect` will return and separate thread will be started due to `setTimeout`

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. There are no separate threads in one worker. `setTimeout` doesn't create threads. Why do you use `async`/`await` in `setTimeout`. That doesn't make sense. Why not `setTimeout(() => { this.connect(config); }, parseInt(process.env.DB_RETRY_INTERVAL));`?

Comment: You probably should read about the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop)

Comment: @jabaa, I used `async/await` in `setTimeout` in `connect` function by mistake. Copied from `query` function. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @jabaa, As `setTimeout` doesn't create threads, does this means `setTimeout(() => { this.connect(config); }, 5000)` is recursion? Will `setTimeout` calls keep the control inside `connect` function? Will `connect` not return to caller when `setTimeout` is sleeping for 5 sconds?

Comment: It's not recursion. Read about the event loop. It explains it. The whole function is not blocking. It's also explained in the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254797/discussion-between-syed-rafey-husain-and-jabaa).

Comment: JavaScript has its own Circuit Breaker libraries, eg [Opossum](https://github.com/nodeshift/opossum). There's no need to risk your own faulty implementation

Answer (score 0):

Following implementation worked for me:

```js
const mysql = require("mysql");

class Database {
  databaseName: string | undefined;

  connection: any;

  config?: {
    host: string;
    user: string;
    password: string;
    port: string;
    database?: string;
  };

  constructor() { }

  public async connect(config) {
    const connectToDatabase = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
        this.config = config;

        this.connection.connect((err) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else
            resolve(this.connection);
        });

      });
    };

    try {
      const connection = await this.retry(connectToDatabase, parseInt(process.env.DB_MAX_RETRY), parseInt(process.env.DB_RETRY_INTERVAL));
      this.connection = connection;
      this.config = config;
      console.log(`Database connection established for: ${this.config.database}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`Error connecting to the database: ${err.message}`);
      throw err;
    }
  }

  // Yea I'm not gonna define the type on this lol
  public async query(sql: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.connection.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        resolve(rows);
      });
    });
  }

  retry = (fn, maxRetries: number, delay: number): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let retries = 0;

      function tryNow() {
        fn()
          .then((result) => {
            resolve(result);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            retries++;
            if (retries <= maxRetries || maxRetries < 0) {
              console.log(`Retry ${retries} of ${maxRetries} in ${delay}ms due to error: ${error}`);
              setTimeout(tryNow, delay);
            } else {
              reject(new Error(`Maximum retries (${maxRetries}) exceeded. Last error: ${error}`));
            }
          });
      }

      tryNow();
    });
  }
}

export default Database;
```

And this is how `connect` should be called:

```js
import Database from "./Database";

export const database = new Database();

const createConnection = async (config) => {
    console.log("Started connecting to database...")
    await database.connect(config);
    console.log("Successfully connected to database...")
}

export default createConnection;
```